# How to prevent red cross using a custom font in C#

Tags: c#

I have a class creating a new Font using privateFontCollection. The class passes the created font to other (GUI) classes. They set the passed font on the buttons they contain. When I run the project, the font show just fine at first, but later on (probably after some redraws), some buttons become a red cross. When I at this point try to create a new button, an unhandled ArgumentException causes the program to end.

```
smallButtonFont = {Name = '((System.Drawing.Font)(smallButtonFont)).fontFamily.Name' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' Size=12.0}
```

So somehow the font gets altered while I only read it after creating it once. How could I prevent this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When I read the title I was wondering what you had against the Red Cross.

Comment: ye, they should stick to medical work and leave the programming to us